# using chrome console to evaluate access ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to use chrome develop tool console to evaluate the element in ng-repeat?

for example.

ng-repeat="friend in friends"

i've tried to select the element and use $0.getAttribute("ng-repeat").friend

but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

angular.element($0).scope().friend should work.